# Passing Different Arguments When Running Docker Image Multiple Times

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I need to give an argument while running Docker Image which will be a number from 0-3.

Dockerfile has the following:

```
WORKDIR "mydir/build"
CMD ./maker oneapp > /artifacts/oneapp_$1.log ; ./maker twoapp > /artifacts/twoapp_$1.log ; ./maker -j13 threeapp > /artifacts/threeapp_$1.log
```

I will be running the same Docker Image multiple times so I need logs to be saved in /artifacts appended with _0, _1, _2, _3, as appropriate.

I tried keeping this in Docker file but don't want to pass this full line as argument while running docker.

> ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
>
> ./maker oneapp > /artifacts/oneapp_$1.log ; ./maker twoapp >
> /artifacts/twoapp_$1.log ; ./maker -j13 threeapp >
> /artifacts/threeapp_$1.log

Is it possible to do this? What do I need to modify in Dockerfile to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply inject your parameter as an ENV.

Declare an [`ENV` in your Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env).

```
ENV suffix 0
./maker oneapp > /artifacts/oneapp_${suffix}.log
```

> The environment variables set using `ENV` will persist when a container is run from the resulting image.
>   You can view the values using `docker inspect`, and change them using `docker run --env <key>=<value>`.

That way, you can declare that [`ENV` on docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/env-environment-variables), and benefit from its value in the running container.

> the operator can set any environment variable in the container by using one or more -e flags, even overriding those mentioned above, or already defined by the developer with a Dockerfile ENV:

In your case, for instance:

```
docker run -e suffix=2 <image_name>
```

Comment: This is nice &elegant approach.

Comment: I have added ENV count 0 and CMD ./maker oneapp > /artifacts/oneapp_${suffix}.log in Dockerfile but seeing this error: root@onl-dev:/data/sept15/target-docker# docker run -it target -e count=0
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "-e": executable file not found in $PATH.

Comment: @Sweety yes: `docker run` needs an image name to run (create a container from it). Your command has no image name.

Comment: Changed the order and it worked, thanks a lot! 
docker run -it -e count=0 target