# Pass optional arguments when running a Docker image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a Docker file based on windowsservercore, which I am hosting an ASP.net Core web application.

Snippet from docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["my.exe"]
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000
```

When running the docker image with the below command, I'm trying to pass optional arguments that will be passed down to my exe endpoint.

```
docker rm myapp
docker run --net="host" --name myapp -p 5000:5000 myappservice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have either a `CMD`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Or an `ENTRYPOINT`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

In your Dockerfile.

You should read this discussion:

[What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

And also that one:

[Passing Different Arguments When Running Docker Image Multiple Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413639/passing-different-arguments-when-running-docker-image-multiple-times?rq=1)

Comment: he is already using entrypoint so this just points to you need to read... sorry.