# Can I pass Docker run arguments to optional Golang flags?

Tags: docker, go

I want to run a simple go script in a docker container. The script has some flags like the two examples bellow.

Flags:

```
dataSource := flag.String("input", "", "Path")
...
concurrency := flag.Int("concurrency", 10, "Concurrency")
flag.Parse()
```

Some flags have defaults set and are optional. Others are mandatory to be set by the user. How would I pass arguments in the docker run command to the go script without having the user to enter all arguments?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git
WORKDIR $GOPATH/go/src/app
ENV GOBIN=/usr/local/bin
COPY . .
RUN go get github.com/lib/pq
RUN go build -o /go/bin/Import
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/Import /go/bin/Import
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/Import""]
```

I've read the docs about [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) but could not find anything suitable for me. Is it even possible or doesn't it make sense?

I've read through posts like this one: [Pass optional arguments when running a Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370404/pass-optional-arguments-when-running-a-docker-image) . They simply pass single arguments, how would I define the default value for those?

Thanks for any help